# Is there a way to find an address of something from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

If you can pin point on a Google map where you know something is can you get the actual address? For example you're in street view and your looking at a building that you want the mailing address for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you come out of street view, into the overhead view, you can right-click on an area and select "What's here?"

This should give you the street address - works in many, but not necessarily all countries of course - but does appear to work in Canada, where you're from.